# $\mathbb{R}$ and the order-convergence topology

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory, posets

On most partially ordered sets, the order-convergence topology (defined below) is often highly disconnected, often even discrete or [extremally disconnected].[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremally_disconnected_space)

However, the order-convergence topology is connected for $\mathbb{R}$ and coincides with the Euclidean topology.

Suppose that $(P,\leq)$ is a poset such that $|P|\geq 2$ and  connected order-convergence topology. Does this imply that there are $a<b\in P$ such that $\{x\in P: a<x<b\}$ is order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$? If yes, that would make $\mathbb{R}$ kind of a "primary" poset amongst the posets with connected order-convergence topology.

---

**Definition of the order-convergence topology.** Let $(P,\leq)$ be a poset. We define the *order convergence topology*, denoted by $\tau_o(P)$ on $P$. By a *set filter* $\mathcal{F}$ on $P$ we mean a collection of subsets of $P$ such that:

- $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{F}$;
- $A, B\in \mathcal{F}$ implies $A\cap B\in \mathcal{F}$;
- $U\in \mathcal{F}$, $U'\subseteq P$ and $U'\supseteq U$  implies $U'\in \mathcal{F}$.

If $S\subseteq P$ we define $S^u= \{x\in P: x\geq s\text{ for all } s\in S\}$, and $S^l= \{x\in P: x\leq s\text{ for all } s\in S\}$. If $\cal{F}$ is a set filter, then we set ${\cal F}^u = \bigcup\{F^u: F\in \cal{F}\}$ and define ${\cal F}^l$ similarly. For $x\in P$ and ${\cal F}$ a set filter on $P$ we write $${\cal F}\to x \textrm{ iff } \bigwedge\cal{F}^u = x = \bigvee \cal{F}^l.$$

Then we set $\tau_o(P)=\{U\subseteq P: \textrm{ for any } x\in U \text{ and any filter }\mathcal{F} \text{ with } \mathcal{F}\to x \text{ we have } U\in \mathcal{F}\}$. It is not hard to verify that this defines a topology.

Comment: I don't see why an interval $\{x\in P : a < x < b\}$ should be *totally* ordered..

Comment: Intuitively speaking, the order-convergence topology tends to become disconnected quickly if you have a lot of incomparable elements.

Comment: What about the lexicographic square? It does not contain open interval order isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Is the order topology of the lexicographic square connected?

Comment: I think that the long line, also known as the Alexandroff line, might be a counterexample to your claim. In general, to get the real line via a collections of conditions involving the order, one requires some kind of cardinality restriction, e.g., separability in the topological or order-theoretical sense.

Comment: Aren't there points $a,b$ on the Alexandrov line such that $[a,b]$ looks like $[0,1]$, viewed just as ordered sets?

Comment: How is that square defined?

Comment: @TarasBanakh: You mean [this topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order_topology_on_the_unit_square)?  It is connected, but isn't the open interval $((1/2, 1/3), (1/2, 2/3))$ order isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The definition of order-convergence topology is a bit hard for me to understand.  If $P$ is totally ordered, does it reduce to the usual order topology?  Is the answer to your question known in that case: i.e. is it true that any totally ordered set which is connected in the order topology contains an open interval order-isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @NateEldredge I don't understand the order-convergence topology either, but the answer to your second question is no. There are nowhere-separable Aronszajn continua, for instance.

Comment: @NateEldredge - the interval topology of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with their usual total orders is discrete. For any poset, the order convergence topology contains the interval topology, (see 1st sentence of section 2 of   https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4270 ), which   is a bit easier to get a grasp on.

Comment: @Dominic Yes, actually all of them. (But I guess your question was rhetorical.)

Comment: So - the Alexandroff line is definitely not a counterexample

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will show below that for any linearly ordered set $(L, \leq)$, the order-convergence topology coincides with the usual order topology. Thus the answer to the OP´s question is no, since there are linear continua (e.g. a nowhere-separable Aronszajn continuum) that do not contain copies of $\mathbb{R}$.

Fix $a \in L$. To show that $(-\infty,a)$ belongs to the order-convergence topology, let $x \in (-\infty,a)$ and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter with $\mathcal{F} \to x$. Since $x<a$ and $x=\bigwedge\cal{F}^u$, there must be an $F \in \mathcal{F}$ and $b \in F^u$ with $b<a$. But then $F \subseteq (-\infty,b] \subseteq (-\infty,a)$ and hence $(-\infty,a) \in \mathcal{F}$. In a similar fashion we can show that $(a, +\infty)$ is also open in the order-convergence topology and therefore we get that the order-convergence topology contains the usual order topology.

Now fix $U \subseteq L$ open in the order-convergence topology. To show that $U$ is open in the usual topology, let $x \in U$ and consider the filter $\mathcal{F}$ of all subsets of $L$ which have $x$ as an interior point in the sense of the order topology. We will be done if we show that $U \in \mathcal{F}$, and for this it is enough to show that $\mathcal{F} \to x$. If $x$ has an immediate successor or if $x$ is the maximum of $L$ then $(-\infty,x] \in \mathcal{F}$ and hence $\mathcal{F}^u=[x,\infty)$ so $\bigwedge\cal{F}^u=x$. Otherwise since $\mathcal{F}$ contains every interval of the form $(-\infty,a)$ with $a>x$, we have that $\mathcal{F}^u=(x,\infty)$ and again we get $\bigwedge\cal{F}^u = x$. In a similar way we can verify that $\bigvee \cal{F}^l=x$ and hence $\mathcal{F} \to x$.

Comment: Very nice, thanks Ramiro! Despite having thought quite a bit about order-convergence, I still have trouble getting my head around it. Your answer is very helpful.